# Add class on click?

Tags: jquery

I want to add a class to div.color everytime I click on h1.

The issue is that I want a different class to be added to div.color when I click a different h1.

When I click `<h1 data-class="blue">`

`<div class="color">` becomes `<div class="color blue">`

How do I do that? I'm new to jquery so this is quite difficult for me...

```
<h1 data-class="blue">Blue</h1>
<h1 data-class="green">Green</h1>

<div class="color">I'm changing colour here.</div>

<script>
$('h1.color').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css({"background":"attr('data-class')"});
});
 </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Vera! The way it works is that you're supposed to accept the best answer after you're done asking.. there are some excellent ones to choose from below.

Answer (score 5):

Try this ;)

I have added blue and green color to check is this working or not.

```js
$(function() {
  $('h1.addClass').on('click', function() {
    $('div.color').removeClass('blue green').addClass($(this).attr('data-class'));
  });
});
```

```css
.blue{
  color: #00F;
}

.green{
  color: #0F0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="addClass" data-class="blue">Blue</h1>
<h1 class="addClass" data-class="green">Green</h1>

<div class="color">I'm changing colour here.</div>
```

Comment: what if more than two classes, I mean do we have to remove all the classes. what if there are 100. ?. what if we do not no the class name ?

Comment: @AnuradhS On `h1` click we don't need to worry about other classes.

Comment: I meant, when you click on h1, you remove all available classes, before you add new class. What I am asking is what if there more than 2 like  `blue, green,red, orange,yellow,purple,etc`, then you have to remove all.

Comment: @AnuradhS We can do that and can't let say if we have added some other class from other part of code that should be on the element(`div.color`) any of the new class is being added to element(`div.color`);

Comment: yes, any of the new class is being added to element, what if user click on same element twice, then you have to remove first, like you have done in you code.

Comment: @AnuradhS What you wanna from my side?

Answer (score 1):

First off if you want to select all h1-elements the selector should be "h1". If you use "h1.color" you are trying to find h1-element with css-class "color" which you don't have.

And if you want to add a class to color div, you should use jQuerys [addClass-method](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/).

Also worth noting that you should probably wrap it all in [jQuery ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) to be sure the dom is ready when you manipulate it:

```
<h1 data-class="blue">Blue</h1>
<h1 data-class="green">Green</h1>

<div class="color">I'm changing colour here.</div>

<script>
     $(function() {
       $('h1').on('click', function() {
          $(".color").addClass($(this).data("class"));
       });
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Don't forget to wrap in  `$(function(){ ... });`

Comment: @FloatingRock Thanks, added

Comment: @Esko This code will add both classes after each `h1` element click  to the `div.color` element right or not?

Comment: Yes, if you click both h1-elements the div will have both "blue" and "green" css-classes. If you want only the last one you could do ***$(".color").removeClass().addClass("color").addClass($(this).data("class"));***

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```js
var divToAddClass = $("div#color");
$('h1').click( function() {
    var color = $(this).attr('data-class');     
    divToAddClass.removeAttr('class').addClass('color ' + color);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 data-class="blue">Blue</h1>
<h1 data-class="green">Green</h1>

<div class="color" id="color">I'm changing colour here.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides `addClass` method to add classes to elements.
It also provides a `data` function to access custom data-attributes.
Ref: https://api.jquery.com/addclass/ 
https://api.jquery.com/data/

You will also need to write some CSS to define background-color for each such class you wish to add. An example would be

```
<style type='text/css'>
    .blue {
        background-color: #0000ff;
    }
</style>
```

The rest should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are expecting. each an every time user click on `h1` it `remove` the previous `class` and `add`  the new `class`. below is the working demo. I have put some alert to get you an idea. hope this will help to you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<style type="text/css">


</style>

<h1 data-class="blue">Blue</h1>
<h1 data-class="green">Green</h1>
<h1 data-class="red">Red</h1>

<div class="color">I'm changing colour here.</div>


<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var myArray = []; // create an empty array to hold all class names, clicked by the user.

$("h1").click(function(){
    var data_class_name = $(this).attr('data-class'); //get the class name of clicked h1
    myArray.push(data_class_name); //put that class name into the array
    alert(myArray);  //print the array, then you can see what is added last.


    if (myArray.length > 1)  // check for the length of the array, if it is more than 1, then remove the second element from the end of the array, because it is the previous class everytime when user click on a new.
    {
    var getthelastElement = myArray[myArray.length -2];
 alert(getthelastElement);

 $("div.color").removeClass(getthelastElement); // remove the previous classs

 $("div.color").addClass(data_class_name); // add the new class

 var div_added_class_name = $("div.color").attr('class'); // get the current class of the div.
 alert("div class names are :--->  "+div_added_class_name); // print it from an alert tot get you an idea.
    }
    else // if the array length is less than 1, there are no class to remove. so only what you have to do is add current class.
    {
     $("div.color").addClass(data_class_name);

 var div_added_class_name = $("div.color").attr('class');
 alert("div class names are :--->  "+div_added_class_name);
    }

   

});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**note: explanations are in comments. :)**
good luck and have a nice day.